# Is XRegExp compatible with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, xregexp

I downloaded RequireJS single page app [sample](https://github.com/volojs/create-template). In the www/lib folder, I put the XRegExp source [xregexp-all.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slevithan/xregexp/fc69aaf7d9cd56ac06e0cda6cdf2e4625c7dcaf3/min/xregexp-all-min.js) (version 2.0.0).

In www/app/main.js, I added:

```
var xregexp = require('xregexp-all');
print(typeof(xregexp));
```

The console output is:

> undefined

However, requireJS doesn't emit any error messages. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing something wrong. Only **some** versions of the files distributed for XRegExp perform the required `define` call that defines them as RequireJS modules. The one you are using does not contain that call. You can determine this for yourself by searching for the `define(` string in the file.

You'll need to add a `shim` to your configuration so that RequireJS can load XRegExp or you'll have to use a version of the file that calls define, like for instance [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slevithan/xregexp/master/build/xregexp-all-min.js) which is XRegExp 3.0.0 (still alpha). If you want to use 2.x then your config would be something like:

```
paths: {
    xregexp: "../whatever/your/path/actualy/is/xregexp-all"
}

shim: {
    xregexp: {
      exports: "XRegExp",
    },
}
```

Note that this config normalizes the module name to `xregexp`, so you would have to require it as `xregexp`, not `xregexp-all`. In general, I prefer not to have things like `-all` or `.min` in my module names since these may change depending on the situation.

The `shim` tells RequireJS that the value it should export when `xregexp` is required is that of the global symbol `XRegExp`. This is generally how you handle modules that are not AMD-aware.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for "amd", or "define" in a library's source code should be the quickest way to tell if it supports AMD scheme. If not, then it's not (doh!)

However, if the library exposes globals, then you can use RequireJS `shim` to load it up as well as `path` to tell RequireJS where to retrieve it.

```
// Exporting a traditional library through RequireJS
require.config({
  paths : {
    jaykweri : 'path/to/jQuery' // moduleName : pathToModule
  },
  shim : {
    jaykweri : {exports : '$'}  // exporting the global
  }
});

// Using that library in requireJS
define(['jaykweri'],function(globl){
  // globl === $
});
```